# How can I reduce the table size in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have SQL Server 2016 (v13.0.4001.0) 64-bit on a Windows server. The database consists of 7 tables, 6 of them a really small (it's a few rows with configurations) and one main table with the data, that not mapped with the others tables.

Yesterday I got an error

> 1827. Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.table'.'PK_table' in database 'dbname' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full.

So I'm looking for the simplest way to solve that (I'm quite a newbee on that, and it'd be good find simple solution).

What I expect: I need to reduce size of the db (or the my main table) on 2-3 gb. This place is enough for 1-2 years working of my application.

Options I found:

1. MS shared dev. version of SQL Server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-clean-db-free-space-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 and it doesn't have the 10gb restriction. It's a bit hard way, because I have to install and setup it manually on the 8 machines. I've already tried and it's not so easy, because I got this error[image].
2. Use shrink. I'm not exactly sure that it's safe for main data, because I've used that only for logs earlier. But as far as I understand it'd work for me, because my databases work by years without any outer actions. I mean no one work with it\clear it\etc.
3. I'm not sure as well, but I found out `sp_clean_db_free_space` ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-clean-db-free-space-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 ). From describing I got that it can be used for my issue. Maybe I'm wrong.

Also about my main table:

result of `exec sp_spaceused <table_name>`

[image: first]

result of common report for table from ssms:

[image: second]

Comment: You can't just decide to make a database smaller. If you really need to reduce the size of the database then you need to reduce the amount of data. And you [don't want to shrink your database](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/).

Comment: Since you are on SQL 2016 SP1 you can turn on PAGE compression, or store the data in a clustered Columnstore index.

Comment: go to database properties, then files, then check the files size restrictions, and also check the actual files size (both data and log). edit your post with these information. I bet that the file group message is from db log, because it's reaching its limits, you'll need to shrink the log file

Comment: @iSR5 I've shrinked the log file and now it takes smth about 10MB. The issue related only for DB file. The restriction in the "db properties -> files" is 10240, and if I try to increase that I'm getting error that my license is not support more (i've tried that eralier and you can see first point of my answer as a trying to avoid this)

Comment: @SeanLange sorry, I'm not a dba, unfortunately, so make db smaller and reduce the size are the same for me)) the point that I'm trying to make clear is that I got this db from another person, and I'm sure that he never clean that or maintaned that. So this db worked a few years, and I think there are lots of garbage (maybe transactions\some data that was just pointed as deleted, but not really deleted\etc). So I want any easy way to "clear" that.

Comment: Looking at the information you posted it looks like you ran out of storage space for the data. Your primary filegroup is at the max size allowed through the configuration and it attempting to increase the size because you have more data. Think of it like a CD with files. There is only so much space until it runs out room. You are trying to fit more data than your configuration allows. Either allow the primary filegroup to grow larger or reduce the amount of data being stored.

Comment: Yeah. Easiest solution? Upgrade to a paid version. Finished. That is where the limit comes from. No way around it - reduce data. If you have plenty of empty space you can reorganize the clustered index, but that needs space ;(

Comment: @SeanLange  ok, got it.. trying to reduce the data. As you can see on screenshot below in my table 2.570.134 rows, so I delete some old data (873.120 rows) using 'DELETE FROM [mydb].[dbo].[mytable] Where StartTime < '2017-08-07 15:28:32.667';' and... there is only 200MB new free disk space. So reducing data was not full ? I delete ~1\3 of all the data, so I'm expecting to get 1\3 of this 10GB. What should I do to get this disk place ?

Comment: If you have empty space in those files (which would happen when you delete stuff) you don't need to worry about it. That space is allocated to the DB but not populated. It will be used by new data.

Comment: You've got error because your server is 2016 and you installed 2014 dev, you should install 2016 dev: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=sql%20server

Answer (score 1):

@SeanLange Thanks, you were right. After deleting some data, db's physical-size in the folder didn't change, but exception is gone. So, shrink and other methods weren't used. But psysicall allocated disk space a bit confused me during my tries.